# Pygames path to game folder

Tags: pygame

So I have everything for my games organized into folders and if I try to call a graphic it can't find it cause the program can't find the path to the folder. I have been trying to tell it to go back one dicetory but it doesn't work and just shows
C:\Users\ME\Documents\Programs and Games\PygameRPG\Scripts\Database.py..\Graphics\Sprites|"Player.png" Does not exist
and I have looked everywhere around the internet and there isn't one thing I can find that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very pythonic, but...

Try getting the path of your game file, e.g. `C:\Users\ME\Documents\Programs and Games\PygameRPG\main.py` and turn the path into a string (`'C:\Users\ME\Documents\Programs and Games\PygameRPG\main.py'`).

Take that string remove the `main.py` part, something like this:
`path_str = path_str[:-7]`.
It should be one layer up: `'C:\Users\ME\Documents\Programs and Games\PygameRPG'`. Then add the new part of the path. `path_str += '\Scripts\Database\Graphics\Sprites\Player.png'` Use that path to access `player.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you load an image in pygame.

```
img = pygame.image.load("C:\\Path\\to\\file")
```

You must use a full file path if you aren't in the same directory or higher up in the directory hierarchy.

Hope this answer your question! If you have any further questions please comment below!

Comment: So can't just set the directory to the file potions then tell it to go back? Also I am using os as well

Comment: See the answer above tries to do this "going back" business in a hacky, unconventional way. You either use absolute paths (my solution) or organise your folders so that you can use relative path. A relative path weeks be "IMG.png" or "resources/data/IMG.jpg". The files are either in the working directory of the script or in a folder. My point is that paths are not like Terminal commands where to can tell it to go back one.